# Python - Read a CSV and Delete Last Comma of Last Row Value

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code to generate a `.csv` File:

```
sfdc_dataframe.to_csv('sfdc_data_demo.csv',index=False,header=True)
```

It is just one column, how could I get the last value of the column, and delete the last comma in the value?

Example image of input data:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5nVO.png

And the result that im try to make:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEOXM.png

Anyone have an idea or tip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer below as it only required to change value of the last row.

```
val = sfdc_dataframe.iloc[-1, sfdc_dataframe.columns.get_loc('col')] 
sfdc_dataframe.iloc[-1, sfdc_dataframe.columns.get_loc('col')] = val[:-1]
```

Comment: your logic also replaces all rows of specific column but ask is for only last row

Comment: @manjari please check the updated answer. It was not clear that only the last row will remove the comma.

Comment: Yes,now it works. But we can do it in single line. You can check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Once after reading csv file in dataframe(logic shared by you), you can use below logic which is specifically for last row of your specific column replace.

`sfdc_dataframe['your_column_name'].iat[-1]=sfdc_dataframe['your_column_name'].iat[-1].str[:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way**

```
df = pd.read_csv("df_name.csv",  dtype=object)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it eliminate a complete row, not last comma.

Comment: Can you try again? It's okay with me, I tested it

Comment: @hasangc he is asking for last row formatting. Your logic works for  all rows as you have not mentioned last index in your logic